# Collapsing rows on null cells to provide a single row result in SQL

Tags: sql

I currently have data that measures the progress of three groups. Is it possible to reduce the results where like locations produce one row (there will be no data overlap as its all percents out of 100, and each row only carries one group value).

```
Location     Group 1   Group 2    Group 3
  A           22%      Null       Null
  A          Null      Null        52%
  A          Null       26%       Null
  B           27%      Null       Null
  B          Null      Null        29%
  B          Null       44%       Null
```

And I am trying to have the rows collapse on Location to create one line and measure the progress of the three groups.

```
Location     Group 1   Group 2    Group 3
  A            22%       26%        52%
  B            27%       44%        29%
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Working example is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a32fbb/2

```
select 
    location, 
    max(group1) as g1, 
    max(group2) as g2, 
    max(group3) as g3 
from yourTable
group by 
    location
```

Comment: @Taters If you like the solution then please select tick to accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It’s the same solution that I posted shortly beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select location, max(group1) as g1, max(group2) as g2, max(group3) as g3
from YourTableName
group by location
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.